# Ms access Query error with join

Tags: ms-access

I have a problem with ms access query.
I select 2 tables in query: table1 have 2 items and table2 have 3 items and  both are join with billno but when i build the query in query this become [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOy6K.png):

```
SELECT
  productionpurchase.PurchNo,
  productionpurchase.Medicine AS PpurchMedi,
  productionpurchase.Qty AS PPurchqty,
  productionpurchase.Price AS PpurchTP,
  productionpurchase.Srate AS PpurchRP,
  productionpurchase.Desc AS PpurchDesc,
  production.desc,
  production2.ExtraQty,
  production.*
FROM (productionpurchase
  INNER JOIN production ON productionpurchase.PurchNo = production.BillNo)
  INNER JOIN production2 ON productionpurchase.PurchNo = production2.BillNo;
```

Comment: Your results are correct.  You don't seem to understand how joins work.

Comment: http://i296.photobucket.com/albums/mm175/aamir_hussain2/database_zpsjd0fvruw.png

Comment: what are you expecting then?

Comment: i share my snapsht result but duplicate everything